# UItableView doesn't scroll after i add UIscrollview inside every UItableviewcell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am adding a UIscrollview inside my Tableview Cell's because i need to show some options on UITableview cell only if someone scrolls on it.

Now there are two problem which i think are relative somehow,
1) Now my tableview is not receiving UItableview cell clicks.
2) And the cell content doesn't scroll until i scroll the whole table couple of times.

Any idea ??

Comment: the scroll view is getting the touch events, as it needs them for scrolling. You'd need to write some code so that under some circumstances (which ones?!) the scrollview passes the touches up the chain instead of handling them itself.

Comment: Can you please explain this a little. I already know this its just about how to implement it.

Comment: It's not just a coding problem, it is a design problem. If you have a scrolling scrollview within a scrolling table, how is it supposed to work? When I move my finger on my screen, which thing moves? I think you need a different layout or design entirely, most likely. Only way your scheme works is if you can explain the rules -- for example, if the in-cell view scrolls horizontally only or something...

Comment: My scrollview which is inside the UItableviewcell is horizontal scroll only. so this shouldn't be a problem. The problem i think is that the Scollview is receiving all the touch events and tableview cell doesn't know about the click when it happens.

Comment: This is solvable... Is it a plain old UiScrollView now or have you already subclassed UIScrollView?

Comment: Its plain old scrollview